# Angular - How to validate text input data using third party api

Tags: angular

In Angular-14, I am working on a project that inserts using data into the database. Then validate the account number from third party api.

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.createMerchant();
}

createMerchant() {
 this.createMerchantForm = this.fb.group({
  userName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50), UsernameValidator.cannotContainSpace]],
  merchantName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
  accountNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(50), Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')]],
})

onMerchantSubmitForm() {
 this.isSubmitted = true;
 if (this.createMerchantForm.invalid) {
  return;
}
this.isLoading = true;
const formData = this.createMerchantForm.value;

this.merchantService.createMerchant(formData).subscribe({
  next: (res: any) => {
    this.toastr.success(res.message);
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.onClose();
  },
  error: (error) => {
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errorMessage = error.message;
    } else {
      errorMessage = error.error.message;
    }
    this.toastr.error(errorMessage);
    this.isLoading = false;
    }
})
```

}

component.html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="add-form" [formGroup]="createMerchantForm" (ngSubmit)="onMerchantSubmitForm()">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="userName">User Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='userName' id="username" placeholder="Username">
          <div *ngIf="fc['userName'].touched && fc['userName'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="fc['userName'].errors && fc['userName'].errors['required']">Username is required!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['userName'].errors && fc['userName'].errors['minlength']">Username cannot be less than 5 characters!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['userName'].errors && fc['userName'].errors['maxlength']">Username cannot be more than 50 characters!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['userName'].errors && fc['userName'].errors['cannotContainSpace']">Space not allowed in Username!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="merchantName">Merchant Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='merchantName' id="merchantName" placeholder="Merchant Name">
          <div *ngIf="fc['merchantName'].touched && fc['merchantName'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="fc['merchantName'].errors && fc['merchantName'].errors['required']">Merchant Name is required!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['merchantName'].errors && fc['merchantName'].errors['minlength']">Merchant Name cannot be less than 3 characters!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['merchantName'].errors && fc['merchantName'].errors['maxlength']">Merchant Name cannot be more than 100 characters!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName='email' id="email" placeholder="example@email.com">
          <div *ngIf="fc['email'].touched && fc['email'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="fc['email'].errors && fc['email'].errors['required']">Email is required!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['email'].errors && fc['email'].errors['pattern']">Enter Appropriate Email Address!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName='email' id="email" placeholder="example@email.com">
          <div *ngIf="fc['email'].touched && fc['email'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="fc['email'].errors && fc['email'].errors['required']">Email is required!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['email'].errors && fc['email'].errors['pattern']">Enter Appropriate Email Address!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="accountNumber">Account Number<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName='accountNumber' id="accountNumber" placeholder="Account Number">
          <div *ngIf="fc['accountNumber'].touched && fc['accountNumber'].invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf="fc['accountNumber'].errors && fc['accountNumber'].errors['required']">Account Number is required!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['accountNumber'].errors && fc['accountNumber'].errors['minlength']">Account Number cannot be less than 5 characters!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['accountNumber'].errors && fc['accountNumber'].errors['maxlength']">Account Number cannot be more than 50 characters!</div>
            <div *ngIf="fc['accountNumber'].errors && fc['accountNumber'].errors['pattern']">Enter only numbers for Account Number!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" id="cancelCreate" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onClose()">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" (click)="createValidate()"><span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
      <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then I have this third party api:

> https://thirtpartyapi.com/AccountDetail?accountNumber

which appears this way:

```
{
    "AccountNumber": "0987654321",
    "CustomerName": "Frank Akwetey"
}
```

**accountNumber** is the parameter

What I want to achieve is that when the user enters data into **AccountNumber** into the textinput field, the application should validate using the third party api, and also display the **CustomerName** of the corresponding AccountNumber in a label under the accountNumber textinput field.

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to know the length of a valid account number. Let suppose if an account number cannot be greater or less than 11 digits then.

```
if (this.createMerchantForm.value.accountNumber.length === 11) {
  this.http.post(
    `https://thirtpartyapi.com/AccountDetail?${this.createMerchantForm.value.accountNumber}`
    ).subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      console.log(response); //account holder details if valid else no account found or error
    },
    (error: any) => {},
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadUmar. But I want it to be validated before the form is submitted and be displayed on on a label. Secondly, where do I add the if statement you posted?

Comment: you can create a function and bind that with accountNumber <input> tag like this <input (input)="onAccountNumberTyped()" />, then inside this function  paste the above code.

Comment: Hello @MuhammadUmar, The url service is secured with these headers:        "secId": "knt10",
    "secName": "kkcm",
    "secPassword": "nnkml"           How do I add to the code above

Comment: Post a different question for this with relevant information